# Use reflection to set the return type of a private method

Tags: c#, unit-testing, reflections

I've been tasked with writing unit tests for poorly authored legacy code.
The code that I should write tests for can't get changed in any way whatsoever. It's READ-ONLY.(Company policy, don't touch this!)

Please look at the example below:

```cs
//This class can't be changed or refactored. It is what it is.
public class OldUntouchableCode
{
    public string DoStuff()
    {
        var result = DoInternalStuff();
        return result + " new stuff";
    }

    private string DoInternalStuff()
    {
        //Making external calls that DON'T use the dependency-injected clients.
        //This means that the external calls can't be mocked.
        //The output of this call changes depending on what the external call returns.
        //This makes the return value of this method unpredictable.
        var client = new HttpClient();
        /*
         * imagine a bunch of code here that uses the HttpClient to make external calls
         */
        return "The result of the external calls";
    }
}
```

`OldUntouchableCode` represents the code that I must write tests for. The `DoStuff` public method uses the `DoInternalStuff` private method to perform its job. However, this private method makes external calls that can't get mocked.

Trying to write tests for this code results in the following situation:

```cs
var sut = new OldUntouchableCode();
//I need to set the return value of DoInternalStuff() to a specific value, so I can test the DoStuff() method.
//This test might or might not pass, depending on what the external call returns. This return value is unpredictable.
var actual = sut.DoStuff();
var expected = "expected value new stuff";

Console.WriteLine($" Test {(expected == actual ? "Passed":"Failed")}");
```

Since the `DoInternalStuff` method behaves in an unpredictable manner, the output of the `DoStuff` method can't get tested reliably.

To be perfectly clear, I'm NOT trying to test the private method.

I've discovered already that I can find this private method's `MethodInfo` with reflection:

```cs
var methodInfo = sut.GetType().GetMethod("DoInternalStuff", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
```

The above code successfully captures the `MethodInfo` of the `DoInternalStuff` private method. I can see in the debugger that this object contains the correct name of this method.

At this stage, I need a way to tell the runtime to return a specific value(that I determine) from the `DoInternalStuff` private method on this instance of the `OldUntouchableCode` no matter what the external call returns.

In other words, I need to tell the runtime: "Listen! When I run `sut.DoStuff()`, you will eventually invoke the `DoInternalStuff` method. When you do so, return THIS particular string from that method, no matter what occurs inside of that method."

Is this goal possible to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know this is unfortunately impossible, and if you can't modify the internal `HttpClient`, things are gonna get complicated.

The only way you could modify the internally executed request might be the [framework event](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/diagnostics/eventing/frameworkeventsource.cs), but this is too complicated for me to understand how possible this is.

Probably easier would be to choose some heuristic for what can be returned.

For example, a method getting the current IP address by querying `whois.com` will return a different IP address depending on which machine runs it.

You could however check whether or not the returned value is in the correct format for an IP address instead.

For a method querying the current city, you could make a list of possible cities a CI/CD runner or developer might be in and check if the result is included in the list.

Go up a level of abstraction, find out what the method always returns (like "the current city" or "a link-local IPv6 address", and test that.

Comment: Agree that reflection would not help OP. Intercepting and modifying HTTP calls *outside* of an application is on other hand a trivial thing to do (in most cases)...